# Pass the string column of csv file to the Oracle table date column in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, oracle11g

I am uploading the csv file to the Oracle (11g) DB table from PowerShell.
The Csv file contains four varchar2 columns and one date column. I am able to upload the csv file, if I declare the Time1 column of the table as varchar2 in Oracle DB. Error occurred if I declare the Time1 column as Timestamp(2). All columns allow null in Oracle.

PowerShell Version 5.1.19041.1320
Oracle 11g DB

CSV files sample data (MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM format):

```
Ithaca,,TRIANGLE,NY,6/1/1930 22:00
New York Worlds Fair,,LIGHT,NY,4/18/1933 19:00
Valley City,,DISK,ND,9/15/1934 15:30
,,,LA,8/15/1943 0:00
,,LIGHT,LA,8/15/1943 0:00
San Diego,,CIGAR,CA,1/1/1944 12:00
Wilderness,,DISK,WV,1/1/1944 12:00
```

PowerShell Commands:

```
Import-Csv $tgt_file_etl -Header 'City','Colors_Reported','Shape_Reported','State1','Time1' | %{
    $cmd.CommandText = "insert into $table (CITY, COLORS_REPORTED, SHAPE_REPORTED, STATE1, TIME1) 
                        values ('$($_.City)','$($_.Colors_Reported)','$($_.Shape_Reported)','$($_.State1)','$($_.Time1)')"
    
    $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() | Out-Null
}
```

I altered the date format in Oracle using the following commands.

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'MM-DD-RRRR'
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'MM-DD-RRRR HH24.MI.SSXFF';
```

I don't know how to format the date column in powershell. Any help would be highly appreciated.

thanks to all

Comment: Out of ignorance, how would `6/1/1930 22:00` look in the format `MM-DD-RRRR` or `MM-DD-RRRR HH24.MI.SSXFF` and which of these 2 formats are the ones you're looking to convert these dates ?

Comment: To [insert a date/time value into the Oracle table](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/insert_date.php), you'll need to use the [`TO_DATE` function](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php).

Comment: "Error occurred" isn't very helpful; *what* error? You need to either make the NLS setting actually match string format, or use `to_timestamp()`, again with the correct format. But have you considered using SQL\*Loader or an external table to handle this?

Comment: [code]"Error occurred" isn't very helpful; what error?[/code] Sorry. The error is "Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "ORA-01843: not a valid month".

Comment: [code]6/1/1930 22:00 look in the format MM-DD-RRRR or MM-DD-RRRR HH24.MI.SSXFF and which of these 2 formats are the ones you're looking to convert these dates ?[/code] The format I required MM-DD-RRRR HH24.MI.SSXFF. I am able to insert the record as string in the format '6/1/1930 22:00' in oracle directly. But it troubled here. I am new to powershell script.

Comment: I think, I am doing mistake on formatting the string. In Oracle, the following insert statement works correctly. "insert into UFO_REPORTS_PS () Values('','','','',' 12/1/1930 12:10'): but the following statement in powershell gives error. "insert into ....() Values ('$($_.city)', '$($_.shape)', '$($_.color)', '$($_.state1)', '$(([datetime]$_.Time1).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"))')" The error I am getting is : "ORA-01843: NOT A VALID MONTH". I am stuck. Any help to identify the problem? Thanks